# Instagram Graph API problem by using /insights edge

Tags: python, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I'm trying to learn more about Instagram Graph API and I received a problem during my data retrieval.

When I try to use {ig-user-id}/insights edge I get this error.

(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (insights) on node type (InstagramUser)

I'm moving step by step as API documentation shows, but I realized that the Instagram Graph API document is out-dated.

How can I receive basic insights data of a Professional Instagram Account and each media of it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
{ig-user-id}/insights?metric=impressions,reach,profile_views&period=day&access_token={your-access-token}
```

This API endpoint call should work.

Refer to this link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/user/insights

It's updated and working, tried it myself, and even look for all the permission to be given mentioned in the link.

Limitations: 
Insights data is not available on IG Users that have fewer than 100 followers.
Insights data for the online_followers metric is only available for the last 30 days.

Comment: When I try using this endpoint, I get this error:

"message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (insights) on node type (InstagramUser)"

Comment: Is your account public business or a creator account, Only an Instagram account must be a business or a creator account in order to get insights, private user accounts can not get insights, and did you give all these below permissions before generating your access token ?? 

instagram_basic,
instagram_manage_insights,
pages_read_engagement,
pages_show_list,
ads_management,
business_management.

Comment: I think the problem might be that he doesn't have up to a 100 followers